# append JSON data to an anchor tag to be able to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a JSON data that I am trying to append to an `<a>` tag, to be able to click on it and then make some functionality. What I want to see is a customers id number and Name in the list, that I want to click on it and do something. I had no problems retrieving data from JSON, but then I got stuck on how to append it to a an `<a>` and make it a list `<li>`.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "customer.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: parseJSON,
        error: function(){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});  


function parseJSON(data)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < data.customer.length; i++)
    {
        $("#output").append('<ul><li><a href="#">' + 
        data.customer[i].custId + '</a></li>' + ',');
        $("#output").append('<ul><li><a href="#">' + 
        data.customer[i].custName + '</a></li></ul>');

        $("#output").append("<br><br>");
    }
}


<p id="output">  </p>
```

Nothing shows up on a page.

Comment: `<ul>` isn't valid child of `<p>`. Is success callback being called?

Comment: Try changing your `<p>` to a `<ul>`

Comment: @MattL. didn't work

Comment: This is likely unrelated to the code you've provided. Press F12 and do further debugging.

Comment: @charlietfl no , I didn't use callback

Comment: I mean `parseJSON()`... does that get called?

Comment: @MattL. never mind, It actually worked. Thank you. It was really silly error ;)

Comment: @charlietfl yes, its called. I found the issue , Changed <p> to <ul > :) thanks